# Java ArrayList<GenericObject>.remove(GenericObject) returns false, but still decrements size of ArrayList

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, mesh

Here's some context:
I'm working on an assignment to collapse an edge in a mesh that is stored half-edge data structure. This is the immediately relevant code.

```
    System.out.println("Initial Size: " +heds.faces.size());
    if (! heds.faces.remove(currentHE.twin.leftFace));
    {
        System.out.println("We have a twin problem");
            //this will always print 
    }
    // Yet this will always be 1 less than the initial
    System.out.println("After twin removal: " +heds.faces.size());

    if ( !heds.faces.remove(currentHE.leftFace)) 
    {
        System.out.println("We have a problem");
    }
    System.out.println("Third: " +heds.faces.size());
```

So the problem is that "We have a twin problem" always prints, and it should not, yet, "After twin removal" will always be one less than the initial size.

Here's the rest of the info if you feel you need it.
heds is defined in a class "HEDS" (half edge data structure):

```
     public HEDS( PolygonSoup soup ) {
    HalfEdge potentialTwin;
    HalfEdge[] currHalfEdges;
    Vertex curr, next;      
    for (int[] face : soup.faceList)
    {
        currHalfEdges = new HalfEdge[face.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < face.length; i++)
        {
            HalfEdge he = new HalfEdge();

            curr = soup.vertexList.get(face[i]);
            next = soup.vertexList.get(face[(i+1)%face.length]);

            he.tail = curr;
            he.head = next;
            currHalfEdges[i] = he;
            halfEdges.put(face[i]+","+face[(i+1)%face.length], he);

            potentialTwin = halfEdges.get(face[(i+1)%face.length]+","+face[i]);

            if (potentialTwin != null)
            {
                he.twin = potentialTwin;
                potentialTwin.twin = he;
            }       
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < currHalfEdges.length; i++)
        {

            currHalfEdges[i].next = currHalfEdges[(i+1)%currHalfEdges.length];
        }

        faces.add(new Face(currHalfEdges[0]));
    }

    // Checking if every half-edge's face was propery defined
    Iterator<Entry<String, HalfEdge>> it = halfEdges.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry<String, HalfEdge> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, HalfEdge>)it.next();
        if (!faces.contains(pairs.getValue().twin.leftFace))
        {
            System.out.println("DAMN IT!!!!!");
                    // This is never reached
        }

    }
```

Also it does not seem to matter if I remove the twin's face first or not. Also it can be assumed that the mesh is manifold at this point.

Half Edge:

```
public class HalfEdge {

public HalfEdge twin;
public HalfEdge next;
public Vertex head;
public Vertex tail;
public Face leftFace;

/** 
 * while perhaps wasting space, it may be convenient to
 * have a common edge object for each pair of half edges to 
 * store information about the error metric, optimal vertex
 * location on collapse, and the error 
 */
public Edge e;

/** @return the previous half edge (could just be stored) */
public HalfEdge prev() {
    HalfEdge prev = this;
    while ( prev.next != this ) prev = prev.next;        
    return prev;
}
 /**
 * Computes the valence by walking around the vertex at head.
 * @return valence of the vertex at the head of this half edge
 */
public int valence() {
    HalfEdge loop = this;
    int v = 0;
    do {
        v++;
        loop = loop.next.twin;
    } while ( loop != this );
    return v;
}
```

Face code:

```
public class Face {    
/** sure, why not keep a normal for flat shading? */
public Vector3d n = new Vector3d();

/** Plane equation */
Vector4d p = new Vector4d();

/** Quadratic function for the plane equation */
public Matrix4d K = new Matrix4d();

/** Some half edge on the face */
HalfEdge he;

/** 
 * Constructs a face from a half edge, and computes the flat normal
 * @param he
 */
public Face( HalfEdge he ) {
    this.he = he;
    HalfEdge loop = he;
    do {
        loop.leftFace = this;
        loop = loop.next;
    } while ( loop != he );
    recomputeNormal();
}

public Face(List<Vertex> vertexList, int[] faceVertices)
{

}

public void recomputeNormal() {
    Point3d p0 = he.head.p;
    Point3d p1 = he.next.head.p;
    Point3d p2 = he.next.next.head.p;
    Vector3d v1 = new Vector3d();
    Vector3d v2 = new Vector3d();
    v1.sub(p1,p0);
    v2.sub(p2,p1);
    n.cross( v1,v2 );

    // TODO: compute the plane and matrix K for the quadric error metric

}
```

}

Sorry about the last question, I was in a bit of a rush, and was hoping there was a simple solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031446/java-arraylist-removeo-returns-false-but-still-decrements-size-of-arraylist

Comment: That's quite a bit of code. I understand you're in a hurry. It would help us answer your question faster if you could provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: It's right at the top. I was in a hurry before, this isn't due for a while.

Comment: Not trying to give you a hard time, but that's not 100% self-contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a simple problem, but clouded by all your code:

```
if (! heds.faces.remove(currentHE.twin.leftFace));
{
    //...
}
```

It's the semicolon at the end of the if-condition.  That semicolon ends the statement, which is your if statement.  It turns the "then" part of your if block into an empty statement (so *nothing* happens).  Then you have a floating block after it that *always* happens.

Your code executes like this:

```
if (! heds.faces.remove(currentHE.twin.leftFace))
    ; //this empty statement never gets executed, but nothing to execute anyhow


{
    //this will always print (since it's not guarded by the if)
    System.out.println("We have a twin problem");
}
```

In other words, `heds.faces.remove()` is indeed returning true; you just failed to report the result correctly.  Remove the semi-colon and the output should start to make sense to you.

Comment: Figured it would be something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Which JVM are you using? The Sun JDK (i.e. also OpenJDK) has the following implementation:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    if (elementData[index] == null) {
        fastRemove(index);
        return true;
    }
} else {
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
        fastRemove(index);
        return true;
    }
    }
return false;
}
```

Note that the `return false` case can only be caused by `o` not being found in the underlying array.

Also note that `ArrayList` is not a final class - it could be extended by something that is doing the wrong thing.

Finally, your code does not show the declaration of your `ArrayList` - can you include this line from your HEDS class?

Comment: List<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

Comment: @user1032935 Well, that rules out the non-final class possibility. Which JVM are you using?